# Why does fstream create a file in the executable location?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I am making a C++ program in fstream and I have noticed that my program makes a file where the executable file is located.

I have made 2 folders, bin and src. src has main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream file("first_file_with_fstream.txt");
    
    file << "Hello, World of fstream!\n";

    return 0; 

}
```

I compiled it with:

> g++ -o run main.cpp

when I was in the directory src.

After compiling with no errors, I moved run.exe to bin.

I then executed run.exe and found no other files in src as expected. I then found that the file was in bin.

Please explain why this happened!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Why does fstream create a file in the executable location?

You used a relative path name. Your operating system interprets relative paths to be relative to the "current working directory" (or similar). If the current working directory is `bin`, then you will open the file `bin/first_file_with_fstream.txt`.